# Browsing SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Are there any tools for just browsing SQL Server?  I ask because sometimes SSMS is a little heavy weight when I just want to look through the database and find one record, and SQLCMD doesn't really seem like a good choice when browsing through a lot of different records or a lot of large records.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, [QueryExpress](http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx) is a great, lightweight tool (which also can be used from a USB stick) for browsing and querying SQL Server databases.

Comment: This really is a great little tool! If you don't have access to or don't want to use Management Studio / Query Analyzer etc, use this.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using and I really like [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Answer (score 3):

You could try following heterogenous sql clients

### Heidi

It's light weight it can manage both **MySql** as well as **Sql server**

Click [here](http://www.heidisql.com/) to know more.

### SqlDbx

SqlDbx is a fast and easy to use database SQL development IDE for database administrators, application and database developers working in **heterogeneous** database environments.

It can manage **MySql,SqlServer,Oracle,Sybase,Microsoft azure and IBM DB2**.

Click [here](http://www.sqldbx.com/) to know more.